# JQuery JSignature recreate

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using JQuery JSignature.
When I create the signature through

```
     $("#signature").jSignature("setData", strval, 'image');
```

where strval is the string you see below - I am getting error.
(Method setData does not exist on jQuery.jSignature). My question is who do I recreate a signature with the jSignature:

"data:image/png;base64,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"

How do I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
$("#signature").jSignature("importData",strval);
```

Comment: unable to find import plugin with for format 'image/svg+xml;base64'